# Get the average value in a group by other than this row in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get the average value of a column for all rows in a groupby object OTHER THAN this row. Is there any way to achieve it? For example, I would like to know a person's average payment other than this payment record.
I have tried like below, but it would also include the the current row when calculating the mean.

```
otherpay = df.groupby(['id'])['pay'].agg('mean').rename('ptherpay').to_frame()
```